# Handlebars and node dynamic partial not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I'm trying to render a partial dynamically (meaning, the name of the partial is not known until the program runs). I see this is possible using a simple `lookup` subexpression in the [Handlebars docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html).

Dynamic Partials

> It's possible to dynamically select the partial to be executed by
>   using sub expression syntax.
>
> `{{> (whichPartial) }}`
>
> Will evaluate `whichPartial` and then render the partial whose name is returned by
>   this function.
>
> Subexpressions do not resolve variables so `whichPartial`
>   must be a function. If a simple variable has the partial name, it's
>   possible to resolve it via the lookup helper.
>
> `{{> (lookup . 'myVariable') }}`

Here's my setup:

My page contains the following call:

```
{{> components/common/panel content="components/common/category-images"}}
```

Then, in `components/common/panel.html`, I have:

```
<div class="panel">
  {{> (lookup . 'content')}}
</div>
```

When this runs, I get an error that:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    Error: Uncaught error: The partial components/common/category-images could not be found
```

If I call the partial directly with:

```
{{> components/common/category-images}}
```

It works correctly, so I know the file exists. Even stranger, if I include the original line followed by the direct call to the partial commented out, it works:

```
{{> components/common/panel content="components/common/category-images"}}
{{!-- {{> components/common/category-images}} --}}
```

But, as soon as I remove that commented line, I get the error again that the partial is not found. I am very confused by this. Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

I found the following file that seems relevant: `stencil-cli/lib/templateAssembler.js`. Here is the content:

```
var _ = require('lodash'),
    Async = require('async'),
    Fs = require('fs'),
    Path = require('path'),
    internals = {
        options: {
            templatesFolder: Path.join(process.cwd(), 'templates'),
            extension: '.html',
            partialRegex: /\{\{>\s*([_|\-|a-zA-Z0-9\/]+)[^{]*?}}/g,
            dynamicComponentRegex: /\{\{\s*?dynamicComponent\s*(?:'|")([_|\-|a-zA-Z0-9\/]+)(?:'|").*?}}/g
        }
    };

module.exports.assemble = assemble;
module.exports.getTemplateContentSync = getTemplateContentSync;

/**
 * Parses the passed in templates and resolves all of their partials.
 *
 * @param templates
 * @param callback
 */
function assemble(templates, callback) {
    getTemplatePaths(templates, function(err, templatePaths) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        getContent(templatePaths, callback);
    });
}

function getTemplateContentSync(templateFile) {
    var path = Path.join(internals.options.templatesFolder, templateFile + internals.options.extension);
    return Fs.readFileSync(path).toString();
}

/**
 * Parses the passed in templates and returns all of the partials for each one
 *
 * @param templates
 * @param callback
 */
function getTemplatePaths(templates, callback) {
    var templatePaths = [],
        missingTemplates = [];

    if (templates === undefined) {
        return callback(null);
    }

    if (! _.isArray(templates)) {
        templates = [templates];
    }

    Async.each(templates, resolvePartials, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        if (missingTemplates.length > 0) {
            return callback(new Error(
                'The following template(s) are/is missing: \n' + missingTemplates.join('\n')
            ));
        }

        callback(null, templatePaths);
    });

    function resolvePartials(templateFile, callback) {
        var file = Path.join(internals.options.templatesFolder, templateFile + internals.options.extension);
        console.log(file);
        Fs.readFile(file, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, content) {
            var componentPaths = [],
                matches = [],
                match,
                partialPath;

            if (err) {
                missingTemplates.push(templateFile);

                return callback();
            }

            templatePaths.push(templateFile);
            match = internals.options.partialRegex.exec(content);
            while (match !== null) {
                partialPath = match[1];
                if (templatePaths.indexOf(partialPath) === -1) {
                    matches.push(partialPath);
                }
                match = internals.options.partialRegex.exec(content);
            }

            match = internals.options.dynamicComponentRegex.exec(content);

            while (match !== null) {
                if (componentPaths.indexOf(match[1]) === -1) {
                    componentPaths.push(match[1]);
                }
                match = internals.options.dynamicComponentRegex.exec(content);
            }

            Async.each(componentPaths, function(componentPath, callback) {
                Fs.readdir(Path.join(internals.options.templatesFolder, componentPath), function(err, files) {
                    if (err) {
                        return callback(err);
                    }

                    matches = _.reduce(files, function(acc, file) {
                        // remove the extension
                        partialPath = Path.join(componentPath, Path.parse(file).name);
                        if (templatePaths.indexOf(partialPath) === -1) {
                            acc.push(partialPath);
                        }

                        return acc;
                    }, matches);
                    callback();
                });
            }, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err);
                }

                Async.each(matches, resolvePartials, callback);
            });
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Takes a list of templates and grabs their content. It returns simple key/val pair
 * of filename => content
 *
 * @param templatePaths
 * @param callback
 */
function getContent(templatePaths, callback) {
    Async.reduce(templatePaths, {}, getContentReducer, callback);

    function getContentReducer(acc, templatePath, reduceCallback) {
        var file = Path.join(internals.options.templatesFolder, templatePath + internals.options.extension);
        Fs.readFile(file, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, content) {
            if (err) {
                return reduceCallback(err);
            }

            acc[templatePath] = content;

            reduceCallback(null, acc);
        });
    }
}
```

This function is called recursively for every template file / partial, and I can confirm by my `console.log` statement that the `category-images` partial is not in the list of files for the non-working version of my code. It looks like the server is not set up to parse templates from subexpression syntax. This line shows the regex used to find partials:

```
partialRegex: /\{\{>\s*([_|\-|a-zA-Z0-9\/]+)[^{]*?}}/g
```

I'm assuming this runs before the subexpression is evaluated, so the partial never gets recognized. Does this sound like the issue? Is there a reason subexpression partials aren't being evaluated?

Comment: Try to log the partials available with console.log(Handlebars.partials) when it works and when not to see if there is a difference.

Comment: I'm using node, so I don't think `console.log` is available. Is there some other way to check the available partials? I'm very new to node. I tried using the built-in `log` helper: `{{log Handlebars.partials}}`, but it just logs `undefined`.

Comment: console.log should work: https://nodejs.org/api/console.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, please see my update.

Comment: Can't answer maybe you should open an issue https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues

Comment: Did you ever resolve this, have  a problem that seems very similar?